# MVC - View word document in iframe window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, iframe

I have iframe tag in MVC razor file. **I am able to load text, pdf files in iframe**. here, iframe source is nothing but blob path. here blob is nothing but data from azure blob storage. but I am not able to see word document after rendering is complete , iframe shows blank.

below is  iframe window-

```
<iframe id="frm" src="<blob path>"></iframe>
```

is iframe compatible with word document? if not, what are other ways we can show word document file in an MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can use Google Document viewer for this like below :

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

or Office 365 viewer :

```
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

Regards

Comment: I will check. thanks